# Custom y-axis labels not showing properly using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm writing my thesis so I use the `standalone` package to generate PDFs of `pgfplots` graphs and then put them into the main document. I'm having some trouble with one plot though, here's the code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
symbolic x coords={2,3.4,4.8,6.2,7.6},
xtick distance=1,
xlabel={$d$ (mm)},
ylabel={Stiffness (N/m)},
ytick={0,800,16000,24000,36000}, %<-These should be the y-axis tick positions
yticklabels={0,800,1600,24000,32000}, %<-These should be the y-axis labels
x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,0.2)},anchor=north},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.1,0.5)},anchor=north},
width=0.33\textwidth,
tick label style={font=\tiny},
label style={font=\scriptsize},
]
\addplot
table[row sep=crcr,x index=0,y index=1] {
    2 13.914777\\
    3.4 116.21761\\
    4.8 461.65892\\
    6.2 1285.0589\\
    7.6 2901.4203\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I compile this I get the following:
[image: Wrong y-axis labels]
I'm not sure why this happens, I tried changing the position of the `ytick` and `yticklabels` lines but to no avail.

Comment: Are these just some excess zeros? Try `ytick={0,800,1600,2400,3600},` instead of `ytick={0,800,16000,24000,36000},` which has an additional `0` in all but the first entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label work as expected. It is just that in `ytick={0,800,16000,24000,36000}` all but the first two entries are beyond the plot range. If you drop the zeros at the end of these, you get

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
symbolic x coords={2,3.4,4.8,6.2,7.6},
xtick distance=1,
xlabel={$d$ (mm)},
ylabel={Stiffness (N/m)},
ytick={0,800,1600,2400,3600}, %<-These should be the y-axis tick positions
yticklabels={0,800,1600,24000,32000}, %<-These should be the y-axis labels
x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,0.2)},anchor=north},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.1,0.5)},anchor=north},
width=0.33\textwidth,
tick label style={font=\tiny},
label style={font=\scriptsize},
]
\addplot
table[row sep=crcr,x index=0,y index=1] {
    2 13.914777\\
    3.4 116.21761\\
    4.8 461.65892\\
    6.2 1285.0589\\
    7.6 2901.4203\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the comma in the tick labels bothers you, you can remove it with `pgf/number format/set thousands separator={}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
symbolic x coords={2,3.4,4.8,6.2,7.6},
xtick distance=1,
xlabel={$d$ (mm)},
ylabel={Stiffness (N/m)},
ytick={0,800,1600,2400,3600}, %<-These should be the y-axis tick positions
width=0.33\textwidth,
tick label style={font=\tiny},
label style={font=\scriptsize,/pgf/number format/set thousands separator={}},
]
\addplot
table[row sep=crcr,x index=0,y index=1] {
    2 13.914777\\
    3.4 116.21761\\
    4.8 461.65892\\
    6.2 1285.0589\\
    7.6 2901.4203\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```